# Batch file to retrieve filenames from a text

Tags: batch-file

I have a text document with a couple different file extensions used repeatedly. I would like a batch file to extract all the filenames (.jpg, .txt) and create a list. I have never worked with batch files before, but I don't think this should be too difficult.

Sample:

input.txt :

```
Look at the image in image.jpg
Review the format.txt document before continuing
image2.jpg has some nice features
```

output.txt :

```
image.jpg
format.txt
image2.jpg
```

I am trying :

```
@echo off
FINDSTR ".jpg" input.txt >> output.txt
FINDSTR ".txt" input.txt >> output.txt
```

but I get the entire string rather than just the word that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
(
  for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (input.txt) do (
    for %%b in (%%a) do (
      echo %%b|findstr "\<.*[.]...\>" >nul && echo    %%b
    ) 
  )
)>output.txt
```

for every line (%%a) look at every token (%%b). If it has the format `<start of string><some chars><dot><three chars><end of string>`, assume, it's a filename.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the target extensions *enclosed* by spaces (including one space at end)
set "extensions= .jpg .txt "

(
   rem Process just the lines that have an extension
   for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr "%extensions%" input.txt') do (
      set "line=%%a"
      rem Separate each word in this line, preserving special characters
      for %%b in ("!line: =" "!") do if %%b neq "" (
         set "word=%%~b"
         rem If the four last chars in the word is an extension...
         for /F %%c in ("!word:~-4!") do if "!extensions: %%c =!" neq "%extensions%" (
            rem report the word
            echo %%~b
         )
      )
   )
) > output.txt
```